# how to get the selected value of dropdown list of asp.net and store in session variable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, drop-down-menu

```
Dim ename As String = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value
```

this statement is'nt working
any help is appreciated!!

Comment: `Session("yourKey") = DropDownList.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but if you're looking for the text of the item (instead of the value) you need `DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text`.

To store in session, you can just use

`Session("yourKey") = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value`

Comment: this gives an error:
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I tried DropDownList.SelectedItem.ToString() & it worked. I tried without the parentheses too & it still work in visual basic. I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value into a session variable, not only in a String variable:

```
Dim ename As String = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value

Session("yourKey") = ename
```