# pass the selected value of dropdown as a parameter to a function

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I have a user control on my web form as follows
[image]

When the user selects the program year, category and position group dropboxes and click on submit, it should pass the respective ID's as parameters to the following  GetCertificationLevelsList()

with these parameters I should extend this method to get the certification ID and then pass it to the other another  GetGenericRulesList() which should return a data in the form of a collection.

this is the webservice in my project which is named as ..as curriculumtree.asmx file
http://s29.postimg.org/whj4j9fpz/curriculumtree.png

These are the properties that i have used in my web user control code behind
http://s30.postimg.org/44k3lvvb5/prop1.png

http://s15.postimg.org/nqncvgf8b/prop2.png

http://s28.postimg.org/hp8hfli31/prop3.png

http://s21.postimg.org/rykw6eitz/prop4.png

lstCategory,lstProgramYear,lstPositionGroup are all Page level declarations which inherits dropdownlist.
How to pass the selected values as parameters to the webmethod

Comment: Do you know how to get the selected values?

Comment: Do a google search for working examples on [how to get selectvalues from a dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838614/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdown-list-of-asp-net-and-store-in-session-v) I would also read up on `PostBacks` and what objects / web controls trigger postbacks because I am quite sure you will be back asking about how come the values do not persist after `PostBack` hint `__DoPostBack` method research that along with JavaScript or Ajax calls

Comment: `BindData(p1 as Integer, p2 as String, p3 as String,p4 as String)` I would also look up on how to use proper naming convention for method name variables as well :)

Comment: yes @the_lotus. but I would like to get the selected values on the aspx page after i place the user control on my page

Answer (score 1):

If your dataSource is a BindingList like this

`BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> programYearList = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            programYearList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("2013", "year 2013"));
            programYearList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("2014", "year 2014"));
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
            comboBox1.DataSource = programYearList;`

So, you can get the data value

`int yearSelected = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);`